# Is there a way to improve performance of scss file loading in NativeScript?

Tags: css, performance, sass, nativescript

I've inherited a NativeScript app that chooses its root .scss file on startup. The loading and processing of this is taking about 10 seconds on an iPhone 6 and about 5 seconds on an iPhone XR. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can cut this down?

I'm using the latest NativeScript CLI (6.1.2).

I've profiled it using Inspector and it seems to bottom out at evaluating a regular expression (this was done on an iPhone XR where it took about 5 seconds):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsvpl.jpg

Here's the code that is taking the time:

```
import * as app from "tns-core-modules/application";
...
if (DeviceSettings.isTablet) {
    app.setCssFileName('./app.tablet.scss');
} else {
    app.setCssFileName('./app.default.scss');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to halve the time it takes to load my .scss file by using a postcss-loader step, which puts the css through cssnano as follows:

1. Add the following npm packages to the project:

   - `npm install postcss-loader --save-dev`
   - `npm install postcss-import --save-dev`
   - `npm install postcss-preset-env --save-dev`
   - `npm install cssnano --save-dev`
2. Add a `postcss.config.js` file at the same level as the main `package.json` file with the following contents:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
      'postcss-import': {},
      'postcss-preset-env': {},
      'cssnano': {
        preset: ['default', {
            normalizeUrl: false
        }]        
      }
    }
  }
```

3. In `webpack.config.js`, add a `postcss-loader` after `css-loader` to the list of loaders for .css and .scss files:

```
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        { loader: "css-loader", options: { url: false } },
                        "postcss-loader"
                    ]
                },

                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        { loader: "css-loader", options: { url: false } },
                        "postcss-loader",
                        "sass-loader"
                    ]
                },
```

**Note**: I had to use the `normalizeUrl: false` option on cssnano, to prevent it messing with resource urls, e.g. `background-image: url("res://background");`, otherwise the background image would not appear.

To get any further improvements, my plan is to take any page-specific .scss files out of the global `app.???.scss` files and add them when the page loads, i.e. by using `this.page.addCssFile()`.